# The cursor is not aligned vertically when the input is empty, was it a bug of bootstrap/browser?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

I'm using a minimal bootstrap form input & fontawesome icon,

When the input is empty the cursor is slightly higher in its position,

[image]

And when there's something it shows like this (aka vertically aligned)

[image]

I'm not sure if it's a browser bug? I'm using chromium-browser 38 in Ubuntu.

Attached source code:

```
<div class="center-block text-center">
    <form class="form-inline" role="form" action="#" method="post">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                <i class="fa fa-automobile"></i>
            </span>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control" name="q" type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a browser specific behaviour.

Only chrome exhibits this kind of behaviour

You will not see this in Firefox or IE.

And this case is only for an empty input field in Chrome. If you are using a placeholder text for the input box, then there will not be any issue with the alignment.